# How to obtain the time of the simulator in RinSim 4.1.0?

Tags: java, rinsim

I want to know the time inside the `initRoadPDP` method (inherited from the `Depot` class). Is this possible without inserting the `Simulator` object as a field on my class?

```
class MyDepot extends Depot {

  @Override
  public void initRoadPDP(RoadModel pRoadModel, PDPModel pPdpModel) {
    // how to know the current time?
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more code

Comment: Are you familiar with RinSim? Because this is a question specific for RinSim users. (Questions about [RinSim](https://github.com/rinde/rinsim) should be asked on stackoverflow, according to their github). 

I believe this question is plenty clear if you know RinSim. (I only tagged it with java because I had to tag it...)

Answer (score 0):

The `initRoadPDP(..)` method is called during the initialisation phase of `MyDepot`. This happens at the time the `Depot` is added to the simulator, which, for depots, is typically before simulation time has started.

The standard way to get notified of time progress is to implement the [TickListener](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/core/model/time/TickListener.java) interface. Besides keeping track of time, this interface allows you to use the received `TimeLapse` object to perform actions that cost time. However, since the first tick received will always be after any call to `initRoadPDP` this method may not be suitable for this case.

In any case, the code for using the `TickListener` looks like this:

```
class MyDepot extends Depot implements TickListener {
    public MyDepot(Point position) {
        super(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void initRoadPDP(RoadModel pRoadModel, PDPModel pPdpModel) {
        // how to know the current time?
    }

    @Override
    public void tick(TimeLapse timeLapse) {
        timeLapse.getTime(); // current time
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTick(TimeLapse timeLapse) {}
}
```